# NHibernate Mapping Generator is redundantly defining columns from Oracle

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, code-generation

I'm using the latest NMG version 2.0 RC1 to generate Fluent mappings for an Oracle 10g database.  Unfortunately it is detecting multiple instances of many of the database columns, so my output includes up to 5 definitions for each column, all with the same name.

I am working with hundreds of tables, so I really do not want to go through each class file to fix this by hand.

I *suspect* that the problem has something to do with having multiple schemas and that, for each table, NMG is reading and incorporating a table's definition for each schema in which that table is present.  So if I have 5 schemas with a table named `products` that has a primary key of `id`, then my generated mapping for `products` will define `id` 5 separate times.

If that is the case, what I'd like it to do is only look at the schema of the user I specify in the connection string, but I don't see an option for that.

Of course, I could be completely wrong, so I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind; I was wrong about what version I was using.  I thought I had Release Candidate 1, but I actually only had Beta 2.